# Get post based on current time

Tags: wordpress, post, time

I'm currently coding an on air section for a radio website and am trying to display the title and meta data of the current show on air.

To do this I've created custom fields `Start Time` and `End Time` and have set up a query_posts command to retrieve the show post based on the current time being a larger value than `Start Time` and less than `End Time`.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$time = date("G:i");
$showstart = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Start Time', true);
$showend = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'End Time', true);
if($time<$showstart)
        {$startnext = $showstart;}
if($showstart<=$time && $time<$showend)
        {$starttime = $showstart;}
if( date( 'w' ) == 0 ) {
       query_posts('cat=17&posts_per_page=1&offset=0&orderby=meta_value_num&   meta_value_num=$starttime&meta_key=Start Time&order=ASC');
    }
    else if( date( 'w' ) == 1 ) {
    query_posts('cat=18&posts_per_page=1&offset=0&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_value_num=$starttime&meta_key=Start Time&order=ASC');
    }
    else if( date( 'w' ) == 2 ) {
    query_posts('cat=12&posts_per_page=1&offset=0&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_value_num=$starttime&meta_key=Start Time&order=ASC');
    }
    else if( date( 'w' ) == 3 ) {
    query_posts('cat=13&posts_per_page=1&offset=0&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_value_num=$starttime&meta_key=Start Time&order=ASC');
    }
    else if( date( 'w' ) == 4 ) {
    query_posts('cat=14&posts_per_page=1&offset=0&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_value_num=$starttime&meta_key=Start Time&order=ASC');
    }
    else if( date( 'w' ) == 5 ) {
    query_posts('cat=15&posts_per_page=1&offset=0&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_value_num=$starttime&meta_key=Start Time&order=ASC');
    }
    else if( date( 'w' ) == 6 ) {
    query_posts('cat=16&posts_per_page=1&offset=0&orderby=met   a_value_num&meta_value_num=$starttime&meta_key=Start Time&order=ASC');
    }
```

The posts loop looks like below:

```
// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<div id="listenlivebanner">

<div id="showwrap">
<div id="showdetails">
<div id="nowplayingimg">
    <div>
    <div style="height: 150px; display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><?php the_post_thumbnail('onair-thumb', array('title' => ''.get_the_title().'' )); ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="listenlive">
        <h3>LIVE:</h3><p class="showname"><?php $short_title = substr(the_title('','',FALSE),0,18);
                                            echo $short_title; 
                                            if (strlen($short_title) > 17){ 
                                                echo '...'; 
                                            }  ?></p>
```

However, at the moment it's just retrieving the first show post in the order I've set, rather than changing depending on the current time. How to make it work?

EDIT:

Changed from query_posts to new WP_Query but still no luck - now it just displays the title of the page rather than the title of the post I am meant to be retrieving...

Here's the code below:

```
 else if( date( 'w' ) == 3 ) {
    new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 13, 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset' => 0, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC', 'meta_query' => array( 
                                                array('key' => 'Start_Time', 'value' => '$time', 'compare' => '<=', 'type' => 'TIME' )
                                              )
                        )
                );
    }
    else if( date( 'w' ) == 4 ) {
    new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 14, 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset' => 0, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC', 'meta_query' => array( 
                                                array('key' => 'Start_Time', 'value' => '$time', 'compare' => '<=', 'type' => 'TIME' )
                                              )
                        )
                );
    }
```

Comment: No quotes in the variable: `'value' => $time` and see the [usage example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage) for WP_Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd change in your set up:

- name the custom fields as `start_time` and `end_time`
- use `get_posts` or `WP_Query`, but never `query_posts`. See [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)
- prepare the query arguments as an array instead of a string, so you have detailed controls, see the [Single and Multiple Custom Field Handling](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) sections of the docs.
  *It will be*
  **`$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'color', 'meta_value' => 'blue' ) );`**
  *instead of*
  <sup>`$query = new WP_Query( 'meta_key=color&meta_value=blue' );`</sup>

Comment: Still no luck... See the edit above to see if there's anything I've missed out/coded incorrectly?

It's now just displaying the title of the current page rather than the title of the post i'm attempting to retrieve.